Router Push Vue is passing undefined params
I am expecting to pass a value by router.push, this is the component where i want to pass it:
<template>
    //some html
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        //some data
    },
    methods: {
        uploadTemplate(event) {
             if(everythingWell){
                 this.$router.push({name: 'upload-document', params: {value: "example@email.com"}})
             }            
        }     
    }
}    
</script>

**my router: **
const routes = [
    { 
        path: '/upload',
        name: 'upload-document', 
        props: {
            default: true
        },
        component: () => import('./../modules/doc_templates/pages/UploadDocPage.vue')
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
})

export default router;

And the upload component, where i should use the props:
<template>
    <div> 
        <p>value: {{ this.value }} </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        value: String
    }
}

the app change to  the upload route but the value of "value" ins undefined, this is the result i get in the browser:
[Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s) "value" when navigating.
I tried usign props, but its still the same

You did not specify an expected parameter in the route:
const routes = [
  { 
    path: '/upload/:value?',
    name: 'upload-document', 
    component: () => import('./../modules/doc_templates/pages/UploadDocPage.vue')
  }
]
``


To pass parameters through the route, you just need to add in the router that the route receives parameters like this:
{ 
    path: '/upload/:value',
    name: 'upload-document', 
    props: {
        default: true
    },
    component: () => import('./../modules/doc_templates/pages/UploadDocPage.vue')
}

For more detailed information, you can refer to the Vue Router documentation.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
